# Save all the audio from a Node app to mp3 and then live stream it to a shoutcast server

Tags: javascript, node.js, live-streaming, shoutcast, web-audio-api

I am creating an application where the user can mix sounds together and as they are doing that, the audio data gets sent live to a shoutcast server. I for the life of me cannot figure out:

1. A way to capture the audio from the application
2. A way to save that audio as a streamable .mp3 sending that streamable mp3 to a shoutcast server LIVE

My app sends the audio it creates to `var context = new window.AudioContext();` using the Web Audio API (I think, not exactly sure how this works but that is my understanding)

From which I created:   `var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);` to be converted to a streamable MP3. (I believe it needs to be chuncked(?) if my research is correct).

And after that i'm lost. I have a shoutcast server up and running, I got the application creating audio, but now I just need to pipe it out.

Any insight/examples would be greatly appreciated! I am new to JS/Node but am really enjoying the learning process, it's also greatly effecting my sleep :P

**Edit:** The main issue is really capturing all the audio from my web based app and getting it sent to Shoutcast live. I guess any steps in between are just speculation based on my research and understanding thus far.

Comment: Is this a web application? You've got audio on the client side, and want to encode it to MP3 client-side, and send that to a Shoutcast server (presumably not directly but via the server), correct?

Comment: Yes it is a web app running on nodejs. You have it exactly right, but as a matter of ease, any format will do really as the users will just access the shoutcast server to hear it live I presume? Basically the process of getting the audio from the app to shoutcast is the issue. So the whole convert to MP3 thing was just how I thought would be the best way to accomplish it but in reality any way to get the audio piped to shoutcast would be the end game.

Comment: Any ideas @sneep? Seems nobody knows, still havn't figured it out on my end

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://webcast.github.io/